# Location of .vimrc sourced by vim editor in mutt

Tags: vimrc, mutt

I am having trouble trying to customize the vim editor that `mutt` opens while composing and reading emails.

While composing an email, mutt opens a vim text editor. The name of this file/buffer seems to be something like

`/tmp/mutt-Tryer-Inspiron-3268-1000-3494-1425241827100352047`

In my root folder, I have a `.vimrc` that only has:

```
set exrc
set secure
```

Within mutt's vim window, when I type `:echo $MYVIMRC`, I obtain:

`~/.vimrc` referring to the `.vimrc` specified above. If I understand correctly, this setting should allow any vim session of a file in `/tmp/` folder to also refer to the `.vimrc` in the `/tmp/` folder. I placed a customized `.vimrc` in the `/tmp/`folder. However, `mutt` does not seem to source this file. Also, on restarting the computer, the `/tmp/` folder's `.vimrc` file is seemingly deleted.

How can one customize and source a specific `.vimrc` file from within `mutt` for reading and composing emails that is persistent across machine restarts?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
set editor="vim -u $HOME/.vimrc-mutt"
```

in your `~/.muttrc` ?